# Passing a enum value as a tag attribute in JSP

Tags: jsp, enums, taglib

I have a custom JSP tag which is using a parameter which is an enum. This approach is a consequence of using other classes which need this enumeration. The point is I have no clue how to assign an enum value in the EL:

```
<mytaglib:mytag enumParam="${now what do I type here?}" />
```

The only workaround which I found so far was to make the enumParam an Integer and convert it to desired values:

```
<mytaglib:mytag enumParam="3" />
```

I believe there must be a better way to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EL allows the use of Enums!

> There are three ways to set a tag attribute value using either an rvalue or lvalue expression:
>   [..]
>
> With text only:
>
> <some:tag value="sometext"/>
>
> This expression is called a literal expression. In this case, the attribute’s String value is coerced to the attribute’s expected type. Literal value expressions have special syntax rules. See Literal Expressions for more information. When a tag attribute has an enum type, the expression that the attribute uses must be a literal expression. For example, the tag attribute can use the expression "hearts" to mean Suit.hearts. The literal is coerced to Suit and the attribute gets the value Suit.hearts.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html

**Enum:**

```
public Enum Color{ 
   RED, BLUE, GREEN 
}
```

**JSP/ Tag file**

```
<mytaglib:mytag enumParam="${'RED'}" />
```

Tested with Tomcat 7.0.22 as well as Jetty 6.1.26.

Comment: Doesn't this pass a string value, not an enum value?

Answer (score -1):

EL does not support accessing Enums. You should consider using strings .

**Example:**

```
public Enum Color{ 
   READ, BLUE, GREEN 
}
```

You can pass string to your custom tag like below:

```
<mytaglib:mytag enumParam="RED" />
OR
<mytaglib:mytag enumParam="${obj.color}" />
```

In your custom tag you get the enum value like this:

```
Color.valueOf("RED");
```

Comment: In the comment of devpg it shows that enums are supported. And I can also confirm that his solution works.

Comment: Agreed with Peter. This is not correct. In your example, `enumParam="${'BLUE'}"` would work just fine.